# tkinter error label doesn't appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i've been having problems with tkinter.
its supposed to take the number on the first windows textbox
check if its divisible by five and if it is, divide it by five and put it on the popup window. and if it isn't just put the number on the popup and don't divide it by 5.

the code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
answer = 0
def popup():
    global answer
    if (number[-1] == 5 or number[-1] == 0):
        number / 5
        if (int(number) > 1):
            answer = "\number 5 cent coins"
        else:
            answer = "\number 5 cent coin"
    else:
        if (int(number) > 1):
            answer = "\number 1 cent coins"
        else:
            answer = "\number 1 cent coin"
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("answer")
    popup.geometry("330x85")
    answers = Label(popup, text=answer)
    answers.pack
    B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Ok", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
def add_text():
    global number
    number = num_textbox.get()
    print(number)
    popup()
    root.destroy()
root = Tk()
root.title("Number Cent Divider")
root.geometry("330x85")
num_col_mat = Label(root, text="Your number:")
num_col_mat.pack()
num_textbox = Entry(root, bd=1)
num_textbox.pack()
enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=add_text)
enter_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and no error appears but the label on the popup does not appear at:

```
popup = tk.Tk()
popup.wm_title("answer")
popup.geometry("330x85")
answers = Label(popup, text=answer)
answers.pack
B1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Ok", command=popup.destroy)
B1.pack()
```

Comment: Don't create multiple Tk() instances. Use [Toplevel()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) instead as your `popup`.

Comment: @Lafexlos i tried using Toplevel() and it gave me an error that said Toplevel() is not defined Edit: nevermind, it worked. what's the difference though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `pack` on your label object, i.e. add `()` after `pack`.

So, where you pack `answers` should instead be `answers.pack()`.